# Fuzzy Matching Fails But Exact Match Passes

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I've been constructing an ElasticSearch query using Fuzzy Matching to match a user in the system. When running it against a specific group of users (ones with my name), the query appears to work perfectly, but when running it against a random selection of users, it appears to fail.

For the purposes of my testing, I'm passing in the exact values of a specific user, so I would expect at least 1 match.

In narrowing this down, I found that an `exact` match against a name returns the data as expected, but putting the *same* value into a fuzzy block causes it to return 0 results.

For Instance, this query returns a user record as expected:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "firstName": {
                            "query": "sVxGBCkPYZ",
                            "boost": 30
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [

            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "id",
        "firstName"
    ]
}
```

However replacing the `match` element with the below fails to return any records:

```
{
    "fuzzy": {
        "firstName": {
            "value": "sVxGBCkPYZ",
            "fuzziness": 2,
            "boost": 30,
            "min_similarity": 0.3
        }
    }
}
```

Why would this be happening, and is there anything I can do to remedy the situation?

For reference. This is the ES version i'm currently using:

```
"version": {
    "number": "1.7.1",
    "build_hash": "b88f43fc40b0bcd7f173a1f9ee2e97816de80b19",
    "build_timestamp": "2015-07-29T09:54:16Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "4.10.4"
}
```

Comment: querying against firstName and personal.firstName should not be the same. Could you post your mapping? GET <your_mapping>/_mapping ?

Comment: @Lupanoide apologies, I missed a bit of code cleanup for the example. They are the same field.

Answer (score 1):

The match fails because `fuzzy searches` are `term level queries` meaning the query string would *not be analysed* while the data that got indexed, I assume, if of type `text` with `standard analyzer`, would be converted to **svxgbckpyz** in the inverted index.

You can instead, implement `fuzziness` with `match` query as below:

```
POST testindex/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "match":{  
         "firstname":{  
            "query":"sVxGBCkPYZ",
            "fuzziness":"AUTO"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can change the value from `AUTO` to `2` or `3` depending on your use case.

The `exact` match you mentioned also works because query string would get analysed and converts the input string into lower case, which is available in inverted index.

As for how fuzzy query (that you've mentioned) works behind the scene, as per this [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-query.html), is as follows:

> The fuzzy query works by taking the original term and building a
>   Levenshtein automaton—like a big graph representing all the strings
>   that are within the specified edit distance of the original string.
>
> The fuzzy query then uses the automaton to step efficiently through
>   all of the terms in the term dictionary to see if they match. Once it
>   has collected all of the matching terms that exist in the term
>   dictionary, it can compute the list of matching documents.
>
> Of course, depending on the type of data stored in the index, a fuzzy
>   query with an edit distance of 2 can match a very large number of
>   terms and perform very badly.

Note this statement in particular, `representing all the strings that are within the specified edit distance of the original string`

For e.g. some of the words with distance of 1 for `life` would be `aife, bife, cife, dife....lifz`.

So in your case, fuzzy search's automaton would not be able to create term `svxgbckpyz` from input string `sVxGBCkPYZ` firstly because the distance between them is 7 (Remember distance is 1 between `A` and `a`)  which I don't think `AUTO` option can create and even if you configure it to `7`, it may not create the string as there would be huge list of words with distance `7`

Adding one more [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search) for more info. Hope it helps!

Comment: So, if I converted to lowercase on the query would that improve matters? The reason I used fuzzy was for the ability to specify thresholds and weightings (the full query has multiple fuzzy queries), sealing with that might be better served as a different question though.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix Oh yes!! certainly!! converting your input string to lowercase would also be an option. I should've mentioned it but sorry I went ahead with the input string as is. Also note that, I don't think it would be that big of a change if you make use of the solution I've mentioned as it also allows you to specify thresholds and boosting. Its just that, `fuzzy` using `match` would safe guard you to make use of same analyzer during search as that used during indexing.